# Bluetooth not working in Lenovo G500

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in Lenovo G500 laptop of mine, and for some reason the bluetooth is not working. Its not even getting detected I think. Any help?

Running `lsusb` gives me the following

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 5986:0294 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: Add yourself as "this bug affects me" at the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1764645)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put a fix on github

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-3004-4.15.git
cd bluetooth-3004-4.15
./install.sh
```

Reboot

The fix is [upstream](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth?id=544a591668813583021474fa5c7ff4942244d654)

Edit: this bug is fixed in 4.15.0-31 kernel, so after install users can ignore this

Comment: After a kernel update do `cd bluetooth-3004-4.15 && ./install.sh`

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth hardware of Lenovo G500 should be supported by Ubuntu 18.04

1. Check AirPlane mode status (F7) and disable it
2. Enable Bluetooth from Gnome control Center

`gnome-control-center -s bluetooth &`

3. If needed you can list BT hardware with this command

`sudo lshw -class communication`