# Problem with bleutooth on Lenovo G510 and Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

I have problem with bluetooth at Lenovo G510. I can turn on bluetooth but it can not find any device.

I tried this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/1042971/1068251, and it worked for one day. Next day Ubuntu made small update and bluetooth crashed.

Please help me to resolve this problem.
If you need output from commends i can execute and place inside post.

Instruction:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
```

gave me:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc Lenovo Integrated Webcam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[  111.627937] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  111.627958] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  111.627962] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  111.627964] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  111.627969] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  111.774197] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  111.775192] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[  111.791305] Bluetooth: hci0: abcd-Lenovo-G510
[  111.791314] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[  111.803491] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[  111.803495] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[  113.834314] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  113.835288] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  211.634168] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  211.634170] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  211.634174] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  211.651277] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  211.651285] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  211.651289] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  213.663101] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  213.664288] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  412.849614] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  412.850548] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[  412.866557] Bluetooth: hci0: abcd-Lenovo-G510
[  412.866563] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[  412.866585] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[  412.866588] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[  414.887733] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  414.888569] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: The file you need is `BCM.hcd`.

Comment: Great.. How to resolv it? I am noob with Ubuntu. Can you help with instructions? Should I foolow this instructions? https://askubuntu.com/a/1073151/1068251

Comment: There is a link on top of the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working It explains everything. And there are a few answers with instructions.